# Why no Placeholder text on my Ionic 3 project

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic3

I cannot see any `placeholder` text on my project.Can you tell me why? If I create a new project then it works.This is a really strange issue. Any clue about this behavior?

[image]

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">Inline Label</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="Text Input"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

I'm using latest ionic.

> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.15.0
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.15.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.1
> Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
> Node              : v6.10.0
> npm               : 3.10.10
> OS                : Windows 8.1
> ```
>
> Environment Variables:
>
> ```
> ANDROID_HOME : C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
> ```
>
> Misc:
>
> ```
> backend : pro
> ```

Here you can see that it renders correctly.Then where is the problem? I have tested this on the device too. Same horror :(

[image]

Comment: Try adding a `type` property to the input: `<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Text Input"></ion-input>`

Comment: Can't see the computed style but is it possible that it somehow got shifted out of visible part of the parent element? I had this once a few years ago on iOS with ionic, some parent class made huge margin or something. It bugged me for 1 hour before I got the idea to check the style.

Comment: No. Same horror :( @David

Comment: Then probably some other style you have set is interfering with you input element as @DanteTheSmith said. Check the element with chrome dev tools and try removing/adding css selctors to figure out whats causing the trouble.

Comment: Yep, Found the issue. I have given `$text-input-placeholder-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);` globally. That cause the issue. I would like to close this post. Would you like to post it as an answer or? @David

Comment: Sure, I'm glad you could solve it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OP's Feedback**

I have set the `$text-input-placeholder-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);` on `variables.scss` file. That was the issue.

**David's Feeback**

Most probably some other (global, higher level) style is infering with the `placeholder` property. Try inspecting the input element with chrome dev tools and remove/add css selctors one by one to find out which one is causing the trouble (check especially colors, margin, padding, opacity).